# A program using iterator to remove the entries

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, iterator

I have written a code using lists. But even though I used `remove()` method the output is showing all the words without deleting. What should I do to overcome?

```
import java.util.*;
public class ListExample1 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<String> strList = new ArrayList<String>();
    //add data into list
    strList.add("ask");
    strList.add("rule");
    strList.add("left");
    strList.add("right");
    strList.add("fight");
    strList.add("fish");
    strList.add("ask");


    //read the data
    for(String str : strList){
        System.out.println(str);
    }
    System.out.println("--------------------------");
    Iterator<String> iteratorRef = strList.iterator(); 

    while(iteratorRef.hasNext()){
        String str = iteratorRef.next();
        System.out.println(str);
        if(str.equals("ask")){
            iteratorRef.remove();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You print the entry before you delete it. Why would you expect the deleted entry not to be shown?

Answer (score 2):

You have not written any print statement after remove method so you are not able to see the result. Just add print method

```
System.out.println("ArrayList after removal : ");
    for(int i=0; i< strList.size(); i++)
      System.out.println(strList.get(i));
}
```

Comment: or 
  for (String string : strList) {
   System.out.println(string);
  }

Answer (score 0):

You're printing each string unconditionally in the while loop. Is this what you want?

```
while(iteratorRef.hasNext()){
    String str = iteratorRef.next();
    if(str.equals("ask")){
        iteratorRef.remove();
    } else {
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```